# pil python multiple Image independent draw

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, python-imaging-library, draw

I have a database with (x, y) points gathered over time to plot on an image. For better data representation, I would like to generate frames of the image plus a circle on the (x, y) coordinates when they should show up. I managed to do this with the following code, but it takes - in my opinion - too much time (the video is 4250 frames long, and it must be done multiple times, for separate data collections). What I am looking for is a possible optimisation of the usage of the Image loaded initially in memory, so it is not loaded again for every frame but once and for all.

```
subprocess.call(['mkdir', install_path + 'users/' + user.name + '/temp'])
# creates a temporary folder for the pngs generated
r = 8

for i in range(0, 4250, 1):
    valaro = Image.open('pngs/valaro_800.png')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(valaro)
    for d in data:
        if (d.reeltime + 5) * 25 > i > (d.reeltime - 5) * 25:
            # interpret the data to fit on the picture
            xl = d.x * 2.91 + 392
            yl = d.y * -3.06 + 434

            draw.ellipse((xl - r, yl - r, xl + r, yl + r), fill='green')
    valaro.save('users/' + user.name + '/temp/' + user.name + str(i) + '.png')
```

Thanks in advance for the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change...

```
for i in range(0, 4250, 1):
    valaro = Image.open('pngs/valaro_800.png')
```

...to...

```
original = Image.open('pngs/valaro_800.png')
for i in range(0, 4250, 1):
    valaro = original.copy()
```

...so the image is only loaded once, but I suspect this will only provide a minor performance gain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just tested the difference: 31s gained (2m 29secs vs. 3m 1sec) on a i7 3630QM/16Gio of RAM. It's not bad actually, but I don't kown if we could push things further with the same configuration of packages and language.

Comment: @Xander I suspect the bulk of the time is spent in the `valaro.save()` call, if, as you say, it has to write 4,250 PNG files to disk. I presume these files are just used as a temporary input for another tool which creates a video file. Depending on what format that video needs to be, there may be a better approach. Either way, you may get a more significant performance boost if the temp files were stored on a [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive).

Comment: Precisely. I use ffmpeg with overlay filters to present the data gathered on a diagram synchronized with the original video. There's no specific need for the video format, I could do PNG encapsulated in a .MOV container,  but a MOV / H.264 will save space in the end. I imagine we could generate all the PNG in RAM and generate the MOV / PNG file directly, then re-encode in MOV / H.264 for space saving. If python and PIL allows me to do such memory manipulations.

Comment: @Xander Depending on the contents of the input PNG file, you might get a smaller (and lossless) result with [APNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG). If the PNG consists largely of solid blocks of color, which can be [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)'d efficiently, you typically get better results than [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform), which is, AIUI, what H.264 will do.

Comment: Well, with the exception of 4 smileys, 'valaro' is basically 2 axis on a white background. RLE seems a good possibility, yet the background video to be overlayed is much more complex. But I guess ffmpeg could manage the composition of the two quite easily, and supports APNG decoding. So it will be APNG for the data representation on the diagram, then composite it with ffmpeg. Thank you very for your lights :)

Comment: @Xander I'm pretty sure it's possible to get PIL to dump the image data to an in-memory string instead of a disk file, and it also looks like [this apng library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apng/0.1.0) will let you create the animation from in-memory strings. Of course, I could be wrong about the I/O being the slowest part - it could be the rendering if your `data` sequence has a very large number of items.

Comment: @Xander Oops. Missed the part about this being composited with another video. In this case, there's probably not much to gain with APNG. It was really only useful if it could completely replace H.264, but if the other video is not easily RLE compressible, then you may as well stick with your original plan.

Comment: Well, as I said, it may actually help, only to gain time generating the video before composition, saving 4249 saving operations (!) to PIL. I have some difficulty getting the apng library installed via pip to test this solution, but it's another story. I'll post some code if I manage to get thing to work.